# Cannot POST / displayed

Tags: node.js, multer

I have created a directory to save images into when I attempt to upload a picture I get the error message Cannot POST /

I have tried changing the directory name in the code

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('weblinksDB');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
db.serialize(function() {
  db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weblinks (url TEXT, rating INTEGER)");
  db.run("DELETE FROM weblinks");
  db.run("INSERT INTO weblinks (url, rating) VALUES (?, ?)","http://www.bbc.co.uk",6);
  db.run("INSERT INTO weblinks (url, rating) VALUES (?, ?)","http://bbc.com",10);
});

var express = require('express');
var restapi = express();

restapi.post('/insert', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body.url);
  console.log(req.body.rating);
  db.run("INSERT INTO weblinks (url,rating) VALUES (?, ?)", req.body.url, req.body.rating, function (error) {
    if (error) {
      console.err(error);
      res.status(500);
    } else {
      res.status(202);
    }
    res.end();
  });
  restapi.post('/', multer({ dest: './surfcata/uploads'}).single('upload'), function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.file.originalname); //shows the original name in cli
    res.status(204).end();
  });
});
```

the file should upload to the directory

Comment: What's the error on the server side?

Comment: server is up and running.

Comment: Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Comment: Why are you nesting your POST: '/' call inside POST: '/insert' call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, why you are putting your POST: '/' call inside POST: '/insert' call?
Secondly, you can do something like:

```
var path = require('path');
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './surfcata/uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)); //Appending extension
    }
});
var upload= multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/add', upload.single('mainimage'), function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
        return new Error('Only image files are allowed!');
    }

    if(req.file.fieldname=== 'mainimage') {
        var mainImageOriginalName= req.file.originalname;
        mainImageName= req.file.filename;
        var mainImageMime= req.file.mimetype;
        var mainImagePath= req.file.path;
        var mainImageExt= req.file.extension;
        var mainImageSize= req.file.size;
    } else {
        mainImageName= 'noimage.png';
    }
});
```

See if it helps!